# Trouble adding intent to bot

Tags: php, amazon-lex

When trying to add an intent to a bot, I'm getting the following:

```
{"message":"The resource 'SomeBotThatDefinitelyExists' referenced in resource 'TestBot' was not found. Choose another resource."}
```

I'm calling the `putBot` method, and passing the intents below:

```
`'intents' => [
            [
                'intentName' => 'SomeBotThatDefinitelyExists',
                'intentVersion' => '1',
            ],
            [
                'intentName' => 'TestingTheBot',
                'intentVersion' => '1'
            ]

        ]`
```

I am absolutely positive that I've successfully created the offending intent. I can see it in the AWS panel, and via the api. The only difference that I can see between the two intents is that the second intent, 'TestingTheBot' has been included in a previous version of the bot. I am able to add it via the api without issue, but, again, trying to add SomeBotThatDefinitelyExists returns the error above.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with the same issue, I discovered that intents created with `putIntent` don't have a version. After creating an intent, you must call `createIntentVersion`. You can then obtain the latest version from the intent returned by the API. That should be the version you use to set the `intentVersion` property when adding an intent to a bot.